# CodeLite ошибка при компиляции

Tags: c++, mingw, codelite

При компиляции всплывает информация о `TEXT.txt`, о не возможности найти какой-то файл или директорию и входной файл (как понимаю уже скомпилированный файл не находит и не может соответственно запустить):

[image: Вот такая информация всплывает]

Вопрос в следующем: что это за файл `Test.txt`, что за файлы не может найти CodeLite при запуске и как это исправить?

makefile:

```
.PHONY: clean All

All:
    @echo "----------Building project:[ Test - Debug ]----------"
    @cd "Test" && "$(MAKE)" -f  "Test.mk"
clean:
    @echo "----------Cleaning project:[ Test - Debug ]----------"
    @cd "Test" && "$(MAKE)" -f  "Test.mk" clean
```

test.mk:

```
##
## Auto Generated makefile by CodeLite IDE
## any manual changes will be erased      
##
## Debug
ProjectName            :=Test
ConfigurationName      :=Debug
WorkspacePath          :=C:/Users/Егорий/Documents/Krak
ProjectPath            :=C:/Users/Егорий/Documents/Krak/Test
IntermediateDirectory  :=./Debug
OutDir                 := $(IntermediateDirectory)
CurrentFileName        :=
CurrentFilePath        :=
CurrentFileFullPath    :=
User                   :=Хускар
Date                   :=20/09/2016
CodeLitePath           :="E:/Program Files/CodeLite"
LinkerName             :=gcc
SharedObjectLinkerName :=gcc -shared -fPIC
ObjectSuffix           :=.o
DependSuffix           :=.o.d
PreprocessSuffix       :=.o.i
DebugSwitch            :=-g 
IncludeSwitch          :=-I
LibrarySwitch          :=-l
OutputSwitch           :=-o 
LibraryPathSwitch      :=-L
PreprocessorSwitch     :=-D
SourceSwitch           :=-c 
OutputFile             :=$(IntermediateDirectory)/$(ProjectName)
Preprocessors          :=
ObjectSwitch           :=-o 
ArchiveOutputSwitch    := 
PreprocessOnlySwitch   :=-E 
ObjectsFileList        :="Test.txt"
PCHCompileFlags        :=
MakeDirCommand         :=makedir
RcCmpOptions           := 
RcCompilerName         :=windres
LinkOptions            :=  
IncludePath            :=  $(IncludeSwitch). $(IncludeSwitch). 
IncludePCH             := 
RcIncludePath          := 
Libs                   := 
ArLibs                 :=  
LibPath                := $(LibraryPathSwitch). 

##
## Common variables
## AR, CXX, CC, AS, CXXFLAGS and CFLAGS can be overriden using an environment variables
##
AR       := ar rcus
CXX      := gcc
CC       := gcc
CXXFLAGS :=  -g -O0 -Wall $(Preprocessors)
CFLAGS   :=  -g -O0 -Wall $(Preprocessors)
ASFLAGS  := 
AS       := as


##
## User defined environment variables
##
CodeLiteDir:=E:\Program Files\CodeLite
Objects0=$(IntermediateDirectory)/main.c$(ObjectSuffix) 



Objects=$(Objects0) 

##
## Main Build Targets 
##
.PHONY: all clean PreBuild PrePreBuild PostBuild MakeIntermediateDirs
all: $(OutputFile)

$(OutputFile): $(IntermediateDirectory)/.d $(Objects) 
    @$(MakeDirCommand) $(@D)
    @echo "" > $(IntermediateDirectory)/.d
    @echo $(Objects0)  > $(ObjectsFileList)
    $(LinkerName) $(OutputSwitch)$(OutputFile) @$(ObjectsFileList) $(LibPath) $(Libs) $(LinkOptions)

MakeIntermediateDirs:
    @$(MakeDirCommand) "./Debug"


$(IntermediateDirectory)/.d:
    @$(MakeDirCommand) "./Debug"

PreBuild:


##
## Objects
##
$(IntermediateDirectory)/main.c$(ObjectSuffix): main.c $(IntermediateDirectory)/main.c$(DependSuffix)
    $(CC) $(SourceSwitch) "C:/Users/Егорий/Documents/Krak/Test/main.c" $(CFLAGS) $(ObjectSwitch)$(IntermediateDirectory)/main.c$(ObjectSuffix) $(IncludePath)
$(IntermediateDirectory)/main.c$(DependSuffix): main.c
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(IncludePath) -MG -MP -MT$(IntermediateDirectory)/main.c$(ObjectSuffix) -MF$(IntermediateDirectory)/main.c$(DependSuffix) -MM main.c

$(IntermediateDirectory)/main.c$(PreprocessSuffix): main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(IncludePath) $(PreprocessOnlySwitch) $(OutputSwitch) $(IntermediateDirectory)/main.c$(PreprocessSuffix)main.c


-include $(IntermediateDirectory)/*$(DependSuffix)
##
## Clean
##
clean:
    $(RM) -r ./Debug/
```

Comment: А сам код с программой сохранили в файле TEST.txt?

Comment: код я в main.c положил. в коммандной строке через -o я выбирал имя скомпилированного файла?а тут я вообще не понимаю,что за TEST.txt

Comment: Приведите содержимое вашего Makefile.

Comment: @aleks.andr добавил makefile в вопрос.

Comment: @Георгий покажите содержимое `Test.mk`

Comment: @zed Добавил Test.mk в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наиболее вероятная причина ошибки, это то, что у вас в путях к проекту и воркспейсу используются русские буквы (`C:/Users/Егорий/Documents/Krak`). Попробуйте пересоздать `Workspace` в папке, содержащей только английские символы (например, в `D:\workspace`), должно помочь.

Что же касается файла `Test.txt`, то это файл параметров, в котором линковщику передаётся список скомпилированных объектных файлов. Сделано это из-за ограничений на длину параметров командной строки в различных ОС (в Windows это [от 2047 до 8191 символов](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830473), в зависимости от версии) и если командная строка линковщика окажется слишком длинной, то он не сможет ничего сделать. Для проектов типа `Hello World`, это, конечно, не актуально, но вот в большом проекте, с большим количеством объектных файлов, вполне можно столкнуться с этими лимитами.

Файл параметров (он получает имя `ИмяПроекта.txt` и сохраняется в папке с проектом) генерируется автоматически и обычно с ним нет никаких проблем, но если вдруг совет выше, с переименованием папки не поможет, то вы можете отключить его генерирование через настройки `CodeLite`:

`Settings -> Build Settings -> Compilers -> <Имя компилятора> -> Advanced`

пункт `"Pass object list to the linker via file"`

После этого, линковщику будут передаваться пути к объектным файлам прямо через командную строку.

Кстати говоря, `Visual Studio` точно так же использует файлы для передачи параметров компилятору и линковщику, так что, в общем случае, это распространённая практика.

Comment: благодарю, это действительно помогло избавиться от ошибок.хотел спросить еще один момент, а чтобы IDE выводила результат выполнения прямо у себя возможно это сделать!?потому что она пишет информацию о сборке но такое ощущение что не запускает проект(хотя в директории программы лежит скомпилированный .exe )и он вручную через cmd выводит результат.и в таком случае отлаживать программу не представляется возможным.спасибо.

Comment: @Георгий `Build -> Build and Run Project` или горячая клавиша `Ctrl + F9`. Если проблема более сложная, задайте новый вопрос.